# Is there a way to send appengine mail with nodejs without use an intermediary service like sendGrid or mailJet

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client

I am a Python developer, but the circumstances of a project I am working on now, oblige me to find a solution in Node.js

> This is the easy python code to send mail but, is there a google app engine way  like this in nodejs without use an intermediary service like mailJet or sendGrid?

```
def send(recipient, sender, subject, body):
isHTML=True
print("recep: "+recipient)
logging.debug(u'Sending mail {} to {}'.format(subject, 
unicode(recipient)).encode(u'utf-8'))

message = mail.EmailMessage(
    sender=sender,
    subject=subject,
    to=recipient
)

if isHTML:
    message.html = body
else:
    message.body = body

message.check_initialized()
message.send()
```

Thank's for your understanding and help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simple example you posted uses the app engine specific [Mail API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/), available only in the first generation standard environment (`python 2.7`, `java 8`, `php 5.5` and `go 1.9` - see the tabs in the referenced documentation page).

`Node.js` support was added only in the second generation standard environment, which has no such API available.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.